# Why I have this file exe.locked in my root folder from project bin\debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to rebuild my project but it shows me "Access Denied" error and I see in my root folder and I have a locked exe.
I try delet the folder and not can becasue show me "You require permission from computer's administrator to make chnages to this file" but I'm the administrator
Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

**Visual Studio 2019**

[image]

Comment: Did you run your app directly from the debug folder and your app is still running?

Comment: You can try to open your visual studio as administrator

Comment: As a follow-up to @UserNam3. The usual reason for this is that the exe is running. Running an exe takes an exclusive lock on the file. You can't change or delete the file while it's locked, nor can you delete it's containing folder

Comment: @UserNam3 no, I already restarted the computer and the same thing continues.

Comment: @GeorgeKarlinzer not working

Comment: You can also try to delete that file from cmd (as administrator) `del {path_to_file}`

Comment: What if you change folder rights? Right clic, properties, security, advanced. You remove all existing right and add total control for all users.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your project has been hit by a ransomware virus. The locked ransomware is a kind of ransomware. Its main feature is to encrypt files on the user's computer. The encryption suffix of the file is .locked, and requires the user to pay a ransom to decrypt the file. Once the files are encrypted, users cannot access or use them, which is why you get access denied when refactoring your project.

**Solution:**

If a user's files are encrypted by the locked ransomware, the following measures should be taken:

Try to restore the file from backup. If the user regularly backs up important files and stores the backups offline and in a safe place, the files can be recovered by restoring the backups in the event of a locked ransomware attack. (**this method used to save my document**)

**Note:**

Do not pay the ransom lightly. Paying the ransom does not guarantee that the files will be decrypted, and this kind of behavior also has certain transaction risks, which is easy to cause secondary losses.